# VBA UserForm Radio Button Error Handling

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub cmd_OK_Click()

Dim z As Range
Dim x As Object


On Error GoTo errMessage1:
Set z = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlCellTypeConstants)


If OptUpper Then
For Each x In z
x.Value = UCase(x.Value)
Next x
End If

If OptLower Then
For Each x In z
x.Value = LCase(x.Value)
Next x
End If

If OptTitle Then
For Each x In z
x.Value = StrConv(x.Value, vbProperCase)
Next x
End If

Unload CaseForm

Exit Sub

errMessage1:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
MsgBox "Please make sure range has a value", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Empty Cell Error"
End If

Unload CaseForm

End Sub
```

How can I show a msgbox if the any of the radio/command buttons are not selected? Currently, you can press ok when no command button is selected. I want the users not press ok unless a selection of a radio button is made or show a message box telling them to choose a selection.

Comment: Are the OptionButtons in a group, or are they the only ones on the form?

Comment: Um, test each button's `Value` and if they're all `False` pop a `MsgBox`?

Comment: Comintern, yes the radio buttons have a group called CaseOption.

Comment: Mat's Mug, there are three radio buttons, when I insert a ELSEIF after the first if of the radio button, then it shows the messagebox when I do not want it. Is there a way for me to group / loop all the values into one? say for y( y = all radio button values) value is null then show message else resume.